# How to get the file extension and size of a document in Google Docs?

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Currently I am implementing .NET Google API to display Google Docs in my ASP.NET web application and I want to fetch the extension and size of Google Document, I got a way to get the extension by sub-scripting the Title of the Document from last index of "." but in case of spreadsheet it can be possible as it just contains the name of the spreadsheet document.

Please provide your suggestion here!!

Also, it would be better if you can provide source in C#!!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Drive API to retrieve documents stored on Google Drive and check their metadata, including `fileExtension`, `fileSize` and many others:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

All methods have .NET samples and there's also a complete ASP.NET MVC application that you canuse to get started:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet